# In a non-community property state, which shares get stepped-up basis when held jointly by a married couple and one spouse dies?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, inheritance, cost-basis

Let's say a married couple lives in a non-community property U.S. state. They have a taxable joint brokerage account and periodically buy shares of stock. One spouse dies so the other spouse is entitled to stepped-up basis for half the shares to the fair market value (FMV) on the date of death.

But which half of the shares get stepped-up basis: the oldest, the newest, or some kind of mix? If they have been buying for decades and the stock has appreciated significantly then it could make a huge difference in taxes.

It would make more sense to me if all shares get stepped-up basis, but only halfway between the original basis and the FMV; however this is just my intuition, I have not seen anywhere that this is how it is actually handled.